# Configuring multiple mouse settings

Tags: xorg, mouse, bluetooth, etc

I am a left-handed thinkpad user and have grown used to using the trackpoint in its default right-handed configuration.  When I use my bluetooth mouse, however, I would like the buttons to have a left-handed layout.  In 11.04 (Natty) I can configure this manually using **xinput**, but I would like to have it applied automatically when the mouse is connected.  I have followed the xorg documentation by creating **/etc/X11/xorg.conf/99-ms500mouse.conf** and placing the following into it:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse 5000 button remap"
    MatchProduct "Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "ButtonMapping"      "3 2 1 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

This seems to work initially (GDM seems to be using it correctly), but when I log in and start my X session, the buttons are mysteriously reverted:

> $ xinput get-button-map "Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000"
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

The following is my **/var/log/Xorg.0.log**:

```
[   276.648] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   276.648] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
[   276.649] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000 (/dev/input/event14)
[   276.649] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   276.649] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Applying InputClass "Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse 5000 button remap"
[   276.649] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000'
[   276.649] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   276.649] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: always reports core events
[   276.649] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Device: "/dev/input/event14"
[   276.670] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: ButtonMapping '3 2 1 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'
[   276.670] (--) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Found 8 mouse buttons
[   276.670] (--) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Found scroll wheel(s)
[   276.670] (--) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Found relative axes
[   276.670] (--) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Found x and y relative axes
[   276.670] (--) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Found absolute axes
[   276.670] (II) evdev-grail: failed to open grail, no gesture support
[   276.670] (II) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Configuring as mouse
[   276.670] (II) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: Adding scrollwheel support
[   276.670] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   276.670] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   276.670] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/input14/event14"
[   276.670] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000" (type: MOUSE)
[   276.670] (II) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: initialized for relative axes.
[   276.670] (WW) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: ignoring absolute axes.
[   276.670] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   276.670] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   276.671] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   276.671] (**) Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
```

As you can see, it appears to apply the button mapping I want (that is, swap buttons 3 and 1 and disable all others), but once the session starts this is gone.  How do I make sure these settings stick?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem.  gnome-settings-daemon is overriding the settings I give the mouse with the system-wide settings (which are set to right-handed).  The only way to avoid this behavior is to fire up **gconf-editor** and find the key:

```
/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/mouse/active
```

And unset it.  This will prevent it from overriding the settings specified in an xorg.conf (or fragment file in etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/).